# Make few columns dummy and move values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have the following dataframe with benefits per employee. There are 3 columns to add employees benefits but the benefits itself don't have an exact column to be placed. That is the dataframe:

```
  Country Employee Name         Benefit 1   Total 1         Benefit 2  Total 2  \
0      PT    Employee 1  Health Insurance  1000.0     Car allowance   1500.0   
1      PT    Employee 2  Health Insurance  1000.0               NaN      NaN   
2      PT    Employee 3  Health Insurance  1500.0               NaN      NaN   
3      DK    Employee 4               NaN     NaN  Health Insurance   1000.0   
4      DK    Employee 5               NaN     NaN   Study Allowance   2000.0   
5      DK    Employee 6               NaN     NaN               NaN      NaN   
6      CZ    Employee 7               NaN     NaN               NaN      NaN   
7      CZ    Employee 8     Car allowance  1000.0               NaN      NaN   
8      CZ    Employee 9               NaN     NaN    Food Allowance    500.0   
9      CZ   Employee 10               NaN     NaN               NaN      NaN   

        Benefit 3  Total 3 
0  Food Allowance    500.0  
1             NaN      NaN  
2             NaN      NaN  
3             NaN      NaN  
4             NaN      NaN  
5             NaN      NaN  
6             NaN      NaN  
7             NaN      NaN  
8   Car allowance   1500.0  
9             NaN      NaN
```

I need to make the unique values of Benefit 1, 2 and 3 as column headers and then add the total of the benefit in the correct column. For example, it would look like this:

```
  Country Employee Name  Health Insurance  Food Allowance  Car Allowance  \
0      PT    Employee 1            1000.0           500.0         1500.0   
1      PT    Employee 2             100.0             NaN            NaN   
2      PT    Employee 3            1500.0             NaN            NaN   
3      DK    Employee 4            1000.0             NaN            NaN   
4      DK    Employee 5               NaN             NaN            NaN   
5      DK    Employee 6               NaN             NaN            NaN   
6      CZ    Employee 7               NaN             NaN            NaN   
7      CZ    Employee 8               NaN             NaN         1000.0   
8      CZ    Employee 9               NaN           500.0         1500.0   

   Study Allowance  
0              NaN  
1              NaN  
2              NaN  
3              NaN  
4           2000.0  
5              NaN  
6              NaN  
7              NaN  
8              NaN
```

What would be the best way to do it, taking into consideration the unique values for benefits are unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `wide_to_long()`+`pivot_table()` and couple of methods for cleanup:

```
out=(pd.wide_to_long(df,['Benefit','Total'],['Country','Employee Name'],'drop',sep=' ')
       .reset_index()
       .pivot_table('Total',['Country','Employee Name'],'Benefit')
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(columns=None))
```

Now IF you print `out` you will get your desired output